# How can i call setInterval more than one time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i want to call setInterval with a button multiple times, but when i press the button a second time nothing happens. I have searched for other similar questions but they are in jQuery and dont worked for me.

Edit: What i wan't to do is to repeat the animation by clicking the button.

```js
var element, add, intervalo;
add = 0;
function start(){
 intervalo = setInterval(interval, 50);
}
function interval() {
 add = add + 25;
 element = document.getElementById('teste');
 element.style.left = add;
 if (add > 300) {
  clearInterval(intervalo);
  intervalo = null;
  element.style.left = 0;
  }
 }
```

```css
#teste {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 id="teste">Ola</h1>
  <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you start multiple timers, you'll have the problem that they're all sharing that same set of variables.

Comment: @Pointy What could i do to solve this problem than, is there a way other than creating more variables?

Comment: Maybe you mean to set `add=0` in the clearInterval block.

Comment: Do you want it to run multiple times so you can increase the speed in which `add` increases? If do why not just make the 25 a variable, increase that, and keep the once cycle.

Comment: @ Wobbles, I wan't to be able to click the button again to repeat the animation.

Comment: then the above is correct, you are not resetting any of your variables.

Comment: @Wobbles try to run the code, if you click the button a second time nothing happens. I just wan't to be able to repeat setInterval. If i can do that i will change how the animation will work. That is just a example.

Comment: @Timeºº I get it, but as was said above, you aren't resetting any of your variables, so how do you expect to repeat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting your `add` variable so when the interval is triggered a second time it will go right to the `clearInterval` section.

```js
var element, add, intervalo, btn, element;

add = 0;
btn = document.getElementById('btn');
element = document.getElementById('teste');

function start() {
  btn.disabled = true;
  intervalo = setInterval(interval, 50);
}

function interval() {
  add = add + 25;
  element.style.left = add + 'px';
  if (add > 300) {
    clearInterval(intervalo);
    intervalo = null;
    element.style.left = 0;
    btn.disabled = false;
    add = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#teste {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="teste">Ola</h1>
  <button id="btn" onclick="start()">Start</button>
</body>

</html>
```